# OnGestureListener cancelling out onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, adapter, gestures, android-contextmenu

I have an `OnGestureListener` on my `ListView` because I need gestures over it, but now `ContextMenu` will not work.

**Edited code:**

I have this inside the **`onActivityCreated`** method of my **`Fragment`**  for the `ListView`:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureListener());
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
    listView.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Doing this allow my gestures but, commenting it out brings back my ConextMenu.

I know I can possibly use showContextMenu(v), but not sure where to put it if that is the answer (I have tried in a few places).

Inside my Fragment where adapter is set, I have this empty method,

```
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    return;
}
```

I tried putting that code in there but there is no reference to a View. So not sure how to proceed?

Comment: Why can't you simply use `holder.l1` as the view(I guess that is the view for which the `ContextMenu` should be opened)?

Comment: You mean calling something like ... `holder.l1.openconextmenu(v)`inside of the `onTouch` method?  Also, the view `l1` is a `LinearLayout` so that isn't working.  It's the layout encapsulating each row of the `ListView`. (I tried setting gestures to actual `ListView` in the Fragment and that didn't work.)

Comment: You'll need an activity reference to call that method, something like this `yourActivityReference.openContextMenu(holder.l1);`.

Comment: Can I reference to the Fragment that sets the adapter I'm writing this? It sounds like I can't. When I try, it says `openContextMenu` is undefined.  If I reference the parent Activity, then `cannot make a static reference to the non-static...`

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're doing there. If you are in a `Fragment` you have a reference to the `Activity` through `getActivity()`. The reference to that activity should be passed to the adapter(constructor) and used to open the context menu. I don't understand why you would get that static reference unless you have declared the adapter class as static and you're trying to access `getActivity()` directly?!

Comment: Nope, my answer didn't work, had to erase. Maybe help with the bigger picture?  An `OnFling` is needed over a `ListView`, but this blocks the `ContextMenu` touch action, what is best way to resolve? Or is it my attempt above?

Comment: The `ListView` watches for that event already. Do you want to know when it happens or something else? Anyway you want the fling event on the `ListView` but you set the listener for each row?!?

Comment: You're right, that was totally flawed to do it inside `ListView`.  Changed how I am doig it, see revised code above.   It still does not allow `ContextMenu` to pop up.

Comment: Hey did you manage to make it work? Have a look at this gist( https://gist.github.com/luksprog/5117998 ) and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Never mind that last question. I got it to work!  Many thanks!  Go ahead and put in answer.  I just didn't use it in my `onActivityCreated`.  Moved it to my `GestureListener` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use the `GestureDetector` to "see" the fling gesture and also have the `ContextMenu` opened when long clicking on the `ListView` using the code below in the `onLongPress()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    final int x = (int) e.getX();
    final int y = (int) e.getY();
    int position = listView.pointToPosition(x, y);
    final int firstVisible = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = listView.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);
    getActivity().openContextMenu(v);
}
```

A complete `Fragment` class example [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/luksprog/5117998).

Comment: Thanks again.  There's a reason your rep is 26.4k.

Comment: Only issue I find, if I Long Press an empty listview or the listview header, it gets null... seems I need a null check here `getActivity().openContextMenu(v);` Or something that says , `if not an actual row, don't open`

Comment: @KickingLettuce The `pointToPosition()` method will return `INVALID_POSITION` if the touch event doesn't intersect a row, so you know when not to open the `ContextMenu`.

Comment: Update: EDIT:  `if (v != null) { // open context }` fixes the empty list crash.  But clicking on the LinearLayout in Header is  last issue to resolve.  ALSO,  Logging position (in the method you reference), comes up with position 0 for the header AND row 1.

Comment: @KickingLettuce I don't know what `pointToPosition` returns if clicked on the header. If it returns `0` then don't start the `ContextMenu` if the position is `0`(and also if you've set a header on the list) **or** `INVALID_POSITION`. Otherwise pop the menu.

Comment: My answer was flawed had to start over.  `pointToPosition` returns 0 for header AND first row, so can't check for that.

Comment: @KickingLettuce `pointToPosition()` will return 0 for the first row and the header(what you've said). Now if your code calls that method and it returns 0 have a look if the `ListView` has a header set on it with  `getHeaderViewsCount()`, if it does then don't show the menu.

Comment: `getHeaderViewsCount()` always returns 2 no matter where I click, getting info from `int headerView = listView.getHeaderViewsCount();`  ?  I'm wondering if the best way to do this is in the adapter.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Ok, I've run the sample I wrote but I don't see how the `getHeaderViewsCount()` will return more than `1` or `0`(I've added a `TextView` as a header view). More if you have a header view then the rows positions will indeed be offset by one but you'll not get `0` for the header and the first row. The check should be like this: `if (!(listView.getHeaderViewsCount() > 0 && position == 0)
        && (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION)) {
       // show menu
      }`

Comment: Thanks again, but this crashes at same spot.  One more note, maybe why header's are being returned as 2?  I am using `PullToRefreshListView`

Comment: I believe I found a hack workaround.  Basically the view crashes only on a specific `LinearLayout`.  So I defined that Layout in the `onLongPress` method.  Before opening context menu, I check, before the other checks we already listed, `if (view != that LinearLayout) { \\ open menu }`.   It works.  Is this a horrible hack or a reasonable solution?

Comment: @KickingLettuce You should have mentioned that you use `PullToRefreshListView`, that's quite a big deal especially as, from what I've seen, that library uses special views at the top(where the header should be). Anyway if that check solves the problem take it as a reasonable solution, unless you want to go through the library's code and see exactly what is happening.